# How to autofill the option button in excel user form based on a cell value?

Tags: excel, vba, forms, autofill

[image]

Hi,

I want to let the UserForm to be able to detect the text in cell `B4` and choose the correct option button without any extra click in the userform. May I know how should I achieve that? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this into your userform module:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B4") = "Profit" Then Me.ProfitOption.Value = True

End Sub
```

Couple things to change:

-Change the `Sheet1` to whatever yours is.

-Change the `ProfitOption` to whatever the name of your button is.

Comment: Actually `Me.ProfitOption.Value` is a `Boolean` and not a `String` therefore should be `Me.ProfitOption.Value = True`

Comment: I was just about to comment but it works either way.

Comment: Well *"working by accident"* != *"working because it is correct"* :)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend something like this

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Select Case Sheet1.Range("B4").Value 'evaluate the value of the cell
        Case "Profit"
            Me.OptionButton1.Value = True
            
        Case "Loss"
            Me.OptionButton2.Value = True
            
        Case Else 'if it is none of the above then go into undefined state
            Me.OptionButton1.Value = Null
            Me.OptionButton2.Value = Null
    End Select
End Sub
```

Note that this does not change the cell value if you change the option in the userform. Therefore you would need write the changed state back using either the `Private Sub OptionButton1_Change()` event or a "save" button.